# ex 25 LPTHW (global name pop is not defined)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm currently learning how to code with python following the exercise at the website 'Learn python the hard way' [exercise 25](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html).

The problem is that I can't complete exercise 25 because I have a problem that i can't figure out.

I'm typing into the python console but at the instruction number 8 `ex25.print_last_word(words)` I have this error:

```
>>> ex25.print_last_word(words)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ex25.py", line 19, in print_last_word
    word = words.pop(-1)
NameError: global name 'POP' is not defined
```

this is my code.

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up word for us, praticamente
    divide in blank space tra le parole"""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    '''sort the words, ordina la parola??'''
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    '''print the first word after popping it off, ossia trova pop(0) trova 
    la lettera iniziale della parola..'''
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    '''print the last word after popping it off'''
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    '''takes in a full sentence and return the sorted words.'''
    words = break_words(sentence)
    words = break_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    '''prints the first and the last words of the sentence.'''
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    '''Sorts the words then prints the first and last one'''
    word = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error raised by the Python interpreter does not match the code you posted, since `POP` is never mentioned in your code.

The error might be an indication that the interpreter has in memory a different definition for the module `ex25` than what is in your text file, `ex25.py`. You can [refresh the definition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) using

```
>>> reload(ex25)
```

Note that you must do this every time you modify `ex25.py`.

---

For this reason, you may find it easier to modify `ex25.py` so that it can be run from the command-line by adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = ...
    print_last_word(words)
```

to the end of `ex25.py`, and running the script from the command-line:

```
python ex25.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I don't think that I've completly understand the problem, but I think that I'll try to figure out in the future.